# FieldInfo.GetValue on pointer type not matching debugger reported value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pointers, reflection

Essentially I'm trying to get an internal field via reflection of an internal Unity `DynamicBuffer` class. This field is of type `*BufferHeader`.

`FieldInfo` works, returns a `System.Reflection.Pointer` type, but the value of this pointer is completely different than the one inside the `DynamicBuffer`, at least as reported by my debugger (jetbrains Rider) as you can see in the image below.

This is not just the debugger being confused, as de-referencing the pointer gives back a struct with garbage values leading me to believe the pointer returned by field info really is wrong for some reason.

[image: Here's a picture of the debugger.]

```
public unsafe static void testfieldInfo(DynamicBuffer<T> buffer)
{
    var testFieldInfo = buffer.GetType().GetField(
        "m_Buffer",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var test = testFieldInfo.GetValue(buffer);
    Pointer rawPtr = (Pointer) testFieldInfo.GetValue(buffer);
    BufferHeader* header = (BufferHeader*)Pointer.Unbox(rawPtr);
    BufferHeader headCopy = *header;
    Debug.Log($"pointer Val {new IntPtr(header->Pointer)} original: {new IntPtr((byte*)buffer.GetUnsafePtr())}");
}
```

Comment: You are sure, you have the entire creation/lifetime of your buffer inside the same 'fixed' block ? Putting a pointer as a field into a class is allowed, but it's hazardous to save it for a longer time.

Comment: From your screenshot i do not see a reason why you would cast the result of the `GetValue` call to `Pointer`, the correct cast should be to `BufferHeader*`

Comment: @thehennyy casting directly to Bufferheader* gives me a cast error, FieldInfo can only return a managed object, which then must be unboxed into a pointer.

Comment: @Holger In my actual usecase I'm just swapping out one of the fields inside, only created this for debug.
For a full explanation of what I'm trying: `DynamicBuffer` is resizeable, which in it's code memalloc's a new array chunk then memcopy's the old data. I'm using this array to represent a 2 dimentional field, so when I resize, I need to do a transformation to the old data.
so all I'm doing is copy-pasta-ing unity's internal resize function, but changing the memcopy call to a custom copy. It should work...if I can get access to this field, which for some reason I can't.